# Jenkins publish-over-cifs using jenkins AD credentials

Tags: jenkins, passwords, hudson, publish, cifs

Similar to this question [How can we execute Jenkins job using other user credential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205688/how-can-we-execute-jenkins-job-using-other-user-credential)

I have users who will login to Jenkins using active-directory credentials, and then as part of the job use publish-over-cifs, which must use the same domain credentials they supplied when logging in.

This would require that Jenkins retains the password in memory in order to provide it to the cifs plugin.

How should I do this?

I've added a Jenkins Issue https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22561?focusedCommentId=198490#comment-198490 sponsored for $25 https://freedomsponsors.org/core/issue/483/publish-over-cifs-should-be-able-to-use-jenkins-session-credentials-including-domain-when-jenkins-active-directory-authentication-is-used?alert=SPONSOR#

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, I don't know how to answer your question, but here is a completely off-the-wall hypothetical solution.

The AD user, on their own machine, is already logged in and can use the AD shares/SMB with their logged in credentials.

Design a job that asks the user for the IP address of their machine. Then have the job spawn a Jenkins Slave on that machine, and execute the job on that Slave, so that it inherently gets access to AD.

> This answer probably deserves a downvote