# PsExec works only with "runas /netonly", not with -u and -p parameters

Tags: cmd, psexec, sysinternals

> What I mean:

**If I...**

1. run `runas /netonly /user:computername\username cmd`
2. enter the password for the local admin account "username"
3. then type `psexec \\computername cmd`

I now have a working shell and can run commands as the local admin user on the remote machine.

**However**, trying to run this *without* the runas... and *instead* with the username and password arguments of `psexec` returns an access denied error.

> Example below:
>
> `psexec \\computername -u username -p password cmd`
>
> `Access Denied`

**Note:** Others seem to also have this issue. **My refined questions:**

- *Is this intended behavior?*
- *Why even have the `-u` and `-p`*?

I have also tried disabling the firewall on both my machine and the target machine, and adding the registry key listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828432/psexec-access-denied-errors).

Answer (score 5):

When you initiate a connection with `PsExec.exe`, it tries to use the credentials you are currently authenticated with to copy the `PSEXESVC` to the `\\$machine\ADMIN$\System32` share **VIA SMB**, which enables the communication with your `PsExec.exe` and the `$machine`'s service.

If your currently logged in user account does not have access to `\\$machine\ADMIN$\System32` and the ability to install/start services, then this won't work.

I'm **assuming** if you have access with your user account that this would work.

[Here is a very interesting article from 2004 on reverse-engineering of the original implementation](https://www.ntkernel.com/inside-psexec-remote-administration/).  I am pretty sure it has changed in that time with Windows 7 & Windows 10.

Comment: I see. That would explain why using runas works. But why then is there an option to pass local usernames and passwords along with psexec?

Comment: @MinimumEntropy I really don't know, but I went through this same problem that wasted a lot of my time a couple weeks ago.